# Ruby on Rails Bootstrap login form не отправляет данные

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, devise

Имеется форма входа на сайт стандартный код рельсов на devise\erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--- Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", id: "login-username", type: "text", class: "form-control", name: "username", value: "", placeholder: "username or email" %>
                                    </div>

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", id: "login-password", type: "password", class:"form-control", name: "password", placeholder: "password" %>
                                    </div>



                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>

                                        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                                            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                                            <%= f.label :remember_me, id: "login-remember", type: "checkbox", name: "remember", value: "1" %>
                                        <% end -%>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                      <!-- <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a> -->
                                      <%= f.submit "Вход", id: "btn-login", class: "btn btn-success" %>
                                      <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                        <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                            Don't have an account!
                                        <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                            Sign Up Here
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>



                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

При отправке в логе выдает вот это

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nVWwmcWfxXfXD+K3wRa6BUu77V6RZ+zs7RmLL6jt4u4IMOvpf6GMXHTmNFKLxCERV/hLHzWv4ENtP6F03iPJrA==", "username"=>"v.ser.m@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Вход"}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 62.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас будет больше шансов получить ответ, если вы более чётко сформулируете вопрос. Например, "при отправке формы я не получаю параметры такие-то" или "при отправке формы параметры такие-то приходят с неверным названием".

Во-вторых, если отформатировать код с минимальным отступом в 2 пробела, то его будет гораздо легче читать.

В-третьих, вам нужно очень внимательно прочитать [вот этот раздел](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) рельсогайда - там подробно рассказано о том, как работает `form_for`.

Теперь про ваш код:

Хелпер `<%= form_for(...) do |f| %>` уже даёт вам тег `form`, и дополнительно его использовать не надо. У вас же внутри него лежит `<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">`. Ни к чему хорошему это привести не может, само собой. Для начала удалите внутренний `<form>`

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", 
  id: "login-username", type: "text", class: "form-control", name: "username", 
  value: "", placeholder: "username or email" %>
```

Хелпер `f.email_field`, как и любой другой `_field` автоматически сгенерирует аттрибуты id, name, value, type. Удалите их из вашего кода, должно получиться:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", 
  class: "form-control", placeholder: "username or email" %>
```

Точно так же лишние аттрибуты необходимо удалить из остальных полей.

P.S. Вот этому коду совершенно нечего делать внутри формы. Там же даже коммент есть о том, что он должен лежать в head, а не в body. Кроме того, это не самый правильный способ подключения бутстрапа и jquery в рельсах.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--- Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, в рельсах недавно, изучаю и пишу сайт одновременно, личный проект, благодарен вам за ваше время и силы, что вы потратили на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Mayss, всегда пожалуйста! Приятно помогать вежливым людям :) Всё заработало?

Comment: Да, справился с задачей, огромное спасибо ещё раз! двигаюсь дальше в направление веба на рельсах!)

Answer (score 0):

Получившийся вариант, может кому пригодиться

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-signin"}) do |f| %>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Пожалуйста войдите в систему</h2>
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email Address', class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Введите ваш Email' %>
    <%= f.label :password, 'Password', class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Введите ваш Пароль' %>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <label>
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me, label: false %>
        Запомнить меня
      </label>
    <% end -%>
    <%= f.button "Вход", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```